# Relative maximum width in XUL

Tags: xul

I'm working on a Firefox extension, and am having problems getting relative constraints on the width of elements in the sidebar. For example, I want a description element in the sidebar that will always be as big as the sidebar when the sidebar is resized, and has text wrapping accordingly.

If I put a description in a box with a fixed maximum width, it will wrap correctly, but I can't get relative widths to work correctly using css. If is set the max-width to be 100% in css, it seems to just ignore it and the text will be on a single line and will overflow the sidebar. Any suggestions on how to put relative width constraints on a box in XUL so that text will wrap correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like setting maximum width isn't what you really want. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Box_Model, setting `flex` attribute would be the right approach to make an element fill all the available space (typically `flex="1"`). The corresponding CSS property would be `-moz-box-flex: 1`.

Comment: My problem isn't that it is not filling available space, it is that it takes up more than the space that should be available, overflowing the area given to the sidebar, so that you can't actually read the text, instead of wrapping the text to take up more lines.

Comment: @pjreddie: Just in case, the element only stretches everything if it has no width set - and setting width is possible via `flex` as well.